# Why getTableRow().getItem() is returning a null reference, even on not empty rows?

Tags: java, javafx

So I created this little App with a search bar and a table view. When the screen initializes, I use `tableView.setItems()` to add a fixed list of items to my table. Later, when the user performs a query, a filtered list is generated and I call `tableView.setItems()` again. When the list is being rendered, my code calls methods against `getRowTable().getItem()` to add behaviour to a button in each row. Everything is rendered correctly, however, it seems that `updateItem()` is being called more times than it should, and `getRowTable().getItem()` returns a `null` reference making the program throw an exception.

What is causing this? Code below.

**App.java**

```java
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/com/lib/fxml/search-movies.fxml");

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 768);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**SearchMovies.java**

```
public class SearchMovies {
    @FXML TextField searchField;
    @FXML TableView<Movie> tableView;
    @FXML TableColumn<Movie, String> titleColumn;
    @FXML TableColumn<Movie, String> directorColumn;
    @FXML TableColumn<Movie, Void> likeColumn;

    private ArrayList<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new Movie("Persona", "Ingmar Bergman"),
        new Movie("City of God", "Fernando Meirelles"),
        new Movie("Pulp Fiction", "Quentin Tarantino"),
        new Movie("Gone Girl", "David Fincher"),
        new Movie("Fight Club", "David Fincher"),
        new Movie("Perfect Blue", "Satoshi Kon"),
        new Movie("Prisoners", "Denis Villeneuve"),
        new Movie("Sin City", "Frank Miller"),
        new Movie("Mean Girls", "Mark Waters"),
        new Movie("Breakfast Club", "John Hughes"),
        new Movie("Sixteen Candles", "John Hughes"),
        new Movie("Reservoir Dogs", "Quentin Tarantino")
    ));

    private ObservableList<Movie> observableMovieList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(movieList);

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(item -> item.getValue().titleProperty());
        directorColumn.setCellValueFactory(item -> item.getValue().directorProperty());

        likeColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Movie, Void>() {
            private final Button button = new Button("LIKE");

            @Override
            public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    Movie movie = getTableRow().getItem();
                    button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Someone liked " + movie.getTitle() + " " + movie.getDirector()));
                    System.out.println("Rendering row for " + movie.getTitle() + " by " + movie.getDirector());
                    setGraphic(button);
                }
            }
        });

        tableView.setItems(observableMovieList);
    }

    @FXML
    public void search() {
        String query = searchField.getText();

        if (query == null || query.isBlank() || query.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        observableMovieList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(filterMovies(query));
        tableView.setItems(observableMovieList);
    }

    private ArrayList<Movie> filterMovies(String query) {
        ArrayList<Movie> filteredMovies = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Movie movie : movieList) {
            if (movie.getTitle().contains(query) || movie.getDirector().contains(query)) {
                filteredMovies.add(movie);
            }
        }

        return filteredMovies;
    }

    private class Movie {
        private final StringProperty title;
        private final StringProperty director;

        public Movie(String title, String director) {
            this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(title);
            this.director = new SimpleStringProperty(director);
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title.get();
        }

        public StringProperty titleProperty() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title.set(title);
        }

        public String getDirector() {
            return director.get();
        }

        public StringProperty directorProperty() {
            return director;
        }

        public void setDirector(String director) {
            this.director.set(director);
        }
    }
}
```

**search-movies.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="610.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.lib.controllers.SearchMovies">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="searchField" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="734.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="192.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#search" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="155.0" text="SEARCH" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="844.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0" />
      <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="120.0" prefHeight="627.0" prefWidth="974.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="120.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="titleColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Title" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="directorColumn" prefWidth="433.0" text="Director" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="likeColumn" prefWidth="215.0" text="Like" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Generally, a list can contain null values, so one possible explanation is that you’re passing a list that contains nulls. But there is no way to know without a [mre].

Comment: Sorry for the sloppish question. I came up with a little MRE, I'll be glad if you guys could take a look at it! Please let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I would say that this is happening when the items are being deleted from the table. If I add a check for `if (getTableRow().getItem() == null) return;` inside `updateItem()` the program runs smoothly, but I don't know if it's ok to do this because it feels hacky and I don't actually know what's going on.

Comment: Fill the text field with anything you'd like, preferably a query that actually returns something, such as "God" or "Quentin". Then hit search. The table will be updated and then it should throw NullPointerException

Comment: can reproduce it (both in fx11 and current dev) - looks like the cell update is called twice: once from tableRowSkin messaging updateIndex and once from a listener to the row's index (at the first time the item is not yet ready). That's smelly, but not entirely certain whether it stinks enough for being a bug ;) If you feel like it is, please consider filing a report. Until then a null check is a reasonable workaround (as you already noticed :)

Comment: fyi: after a bit of digging, I think this is a bug and filed [JDK-8251483](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8251483). There's also an NPE on autosizing [JDK-8251481](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8251481) when accessing the row/item - until fixed, we need to guard against both row and its item not being null.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I hope this gets fixed, although the workaround already did the job for now.